# I can't load tomcat in browser using my domain ip address

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, tomcat8

**Issue is Fixed!!**

i can load tomcat using localhost but if i used my server ip address it's give me timeout error. Can someone help me? Below i attached screen shots. I'm first time using tomcat. I also paused firewall and check but didn't work

Localhost working fine - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iSv9.png

Server url not working - https://i.stack.imgur.com/01HrQ.png

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i turn off firewall but still same error

Comment: Please don't just add `it's fixed` to your question. Post an answer and accept it (it's perfectly fine to accept your own answer), otherwise the question will stay as `unanswered` in the system forever.